# UITableViewCell reload causes memory leak

Tags: ios

My codes is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SimpleCell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];

    }
    return cell1;
}
```

This  always causes libsystem_c.dylib mallic memory leak 48 bytes.
And the memory leak is accumulated each time when call reloadData.

Wel come any commen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug present in iOS at the moment relating to UIScrollViews.
All you can do at the moment is wait for a system update and hope that it is fixed.

Here is some more information: http://openradar.appspot.com/11081198